# Lograr este efecto con inputs CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

en esta ocasión requiero hacer el siguiente efecto;

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

donde la parte de los números se pueda editar por el usuario, y `USD -EUR` sean una especie de placeholder que estén fijos y nunca se borren, uno de los detalles importantes es la linea central que hace el efecto de división, mateniendo la misma distancia tanto los elementos superiores como los inferiores con respecto a dicha linea.

La verdad vi este efecto en una app, y quisiera saber como lograrlo.

Gracias.

Comment: Hola Grabiela ¿que has intentado? muestra tu código y lo que no te resulta como quieres para que la comunidad pueda ayudarte. Puedes revisar cómo preguntar [https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aquí tienes un ejemplo de como conseguir algo parecido a lo que quieres, tendrías que mejorar un poco el código, yo solo me he centrado en lo que preguntas, pero eso no sería muy difícil y creo que con esto puedes solucionar tu problema.

```js
var inputEuros = document.getElementById("euros");
var inputDolares = document.getElementById("dolares");
function escribirDolares() {
if (inputEuros.value != "") {
  var euros = inputEuros.value;
} else {
  euros = 0;
}
inputDolares.value = parseFloat(euros) * 1.156604;
}
function escribirEuros() {
if (inputDolares.value != "") {
  var dolares = inputDolares.value;
} else {
  dolares = 0;
}
inputEuros.value = parseFloat(dolares) / 1.156604;
}
```

```css
input {border:none;}
input:focus {outline:0px;}
hr {border:0.5px solid black;width:220px;margin-left:0px;}
```

```html
<div>
<input type="number" id="euros" onkeyup="escribirDolares()"/><span>Euros</span>
</div>
<hr />
<div>
<input type="number" id="dolares" onkeyup="escribirEuros()"/><span>Dolares</span>
</div>
```

Comment: estupendo gracias, gracias gracias, un `<hr>` es la clave de este diseno. muy amable por adicionar el `js`. Saludos!

Comment: De nada, un placer haberte ayudado y suerte con tus proyectos.

Answer (score 0):

¿Algo parecido a esto? Te he metido el css dentro del HTML para que veas el efecto que se le puede dar al input simplemente quitándole los bordes y añadiendo una linea. ¿Quieres también la funcionalidad de JS?

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div>
                <input value="20" style="border:none"><span text-align="right">EUR</span>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div>                
                <input value="40" style="border:none"><span text-align="right">DOLL</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```